# Generate .app file and install on a device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I try to install my .app file, but when I install and click on Synchronize (in iTunes) I get the circle of installation beginning on my device and it stop, they're a problem, I don't know where but I see strange things that I can't fix:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be  you  don't have provisioning profile install in Xcode with device UDID added in profile.create development certificate from developer account add UDID in provisioning profile install on device(In Xcode code signing ).

first create Development Certificate

->add APP ID in developer account

->Add Device UDID

->Create Provisioning profile->

-> Set in Xcode(Code Signing identity)

->Run app on Device.

Comment: I have to add an Apple ID account that is enrolled in a Developper Program ? How to create one ?

Answer (score 0):

In itunes you just can install `.ipa` file. (You must have a `provisioning profile for distribution` with your device registered)

For register your account: [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/). It costs $ 99 a year.

When you have the Dev Account [create your provisioning profile](http://lessons.runrev.com/m/4069/l/32957-how-do-i-create-a-distribution-profile-for-ios) and [export and install](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

If you want install `.app` file in simulator, let me know and I share code with you here.

Comment: I can't try on my device without creating a account Apple Developer Program ?

Comment: No, only with the Apple Developer Program account, but there is a rumor in iOS 9 and Xcode 7 this will be possible.

Comment: I'm a newbie in Apple/xCode/iPhone universe it's hard to understand their logic

Answer (score 0):

If your using Xcode 7.1.x now, you should be able to distribute your app to your local device without having to spend the annual $100 bucks.  This feature was recently added to Xcode 7.x series.